# How to get marker longitudes and latitude on marker tap or any details

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-markers

in delegate --- didtapatamrker I have writen

```
   Nslog(@" Tapped  %@",marker.description);
```

The output is

```
        tapped   <GMSMarker: 0x7fd125817250> police (47.099564, 4.413834), <UIImage: 0x7fd125816a00>, {28, 31}
```

Now I can get the long and lat. But how to retrieve it from here and if is there any other way I can get the info of my marker

Comment: Do you mean `maker.position.latitude` and `maker.position. longitude`?

Comment: Look up this reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#a2b9fdae0160d7acf439889ffcdb5f68b

Answer (score 0):

Nslog(@" Tapped  %@",marker.position)